# Encoding Images to Video using JCODEC not working

Tags: android, jcodec

For instance I'm only encoding one image to get an output. Below is what I'hv done. Its not working, and no crashes!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {

        File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(wallpaperDirectory, "output.mp4");
        SequenceEncoder encoder = new SequenceEncoder(file);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.a1);
        encoder.encodeNativeFrame(this.fromBitmap(bitmap));

        encoder.finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


// convert from Bitmap to Picture (jcodec native structure)
public Picture fromBitmap(Bitmap src) {
    Picture dst = Picture.create(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), ColorSpace.RGB);
    fromBitmap(src, dst);
    return dst;
}



public void fromBitmap(Bitmap src, Picture dst) {
    int[] dstData = dst.getPlaneData(0);
    int[] packed = new int[src.getWidth() * src.getHeight()];

    src.getPixels(packed, 0, src.getWidth(), 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight());

    for (int i = 0, srcOff = 0, dstOff = 0; i < src.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < src.getWidth(); j++, srcOff++, dstOff += 3) {
            int rgb = packed[srcOff];
            dstData[dstOff] = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;
            dstData[dstOff + 1] = (rgb >> 8) & 0xff;
            dstData[dstOff + 2] = rgb & 0xff;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am probably a bit late,but since your code helped to accomplish my goal I post my solution. Your methods 'fromBitmap()' work like a charm.

I take screenshots in an AsyncTask while the activity is active. [blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-screenshot-programmatically/](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-screenshot-programmatically/) was quite helpful for that. The images are all saved in the same folder.

Afterwards I add the images into a video:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        try {
            sequenceEncoder = new SequenceEncoder(new File(WHERE_TO_SAVE,"NAME.mp4"));

            for (int i = 1; i<9; i++) {
                File file = new File(path, "/img0000" + Integer.toString(i) + ".jpg");
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                org.jcodec.common.model.Picture picture = fromBitmap(bitmap);
                sequenceEncoder.encodeNativeFrame(picture);
            }

            sequenceEncoder.finish();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `new SequenceEncoder(new File(WHERE_TO_SAVE,"NAME.mp4"));` is not taking `File` type

Answer (score 0):

```
fun convertImagesToVideo() {
    try {
        val output = creteRootPath()
        val enc =
            SequenceEncoder.createWithFps(NIOUtils.writableChannel(output), Rational(1, 1))
        for (bitmap in arrayOfImagesFinalImages) {
            enc.encodeNativeFrame(fromBitmaps(bitmap))
        }
        enc.finish()
    } finally {
        NIOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
    }
}

fun fromBitmaps(src: Bitmap): Picture {
    val dst: Picture = Picture.create(src.width, src.height, RGB)
    fromBitmap(src, dst)
    return dst
}

fun fromBitmap(src: Bitmap, dst: Picture) {
    val dstData: ByteArray? = dst.getPlaneData(0)
    val packed = IntArray(src.width * src.height)
    src.getPixels(packed, 0, src.width, 0, 0, src.width, src.height)
    var i = 0
    var srcOff = 0
    var dstOff = 0
    while (i < src.height) {
        var j = 0
        while (j < src.width) {
            val rgb = packed[srcOff]
            dstData?.set(dstOff, (rgb shr 16 and 0xff).toByte())
            dstData?.set(dstOff + 1, (rgb shr 8 and 0xff).toByte())
            dstData?.set(dstOff + 2, (rgb and 0xff).toByte())
            j++
            srcOff++
            dstOff += 3
        }
        i++
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code might contain the answer, please explain what you've done so it's easy to understand.

Comment: I have modified the answer if you can check this link here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72248481/15122772

Comment: Well that's a different answer on a different question.  You should either fix or delete this answer here.

Comment: no, it's not this 'fun fromBitmap' from this answer can extract an image in different colors than the original one but the answer from the link which is the full answer can extract an image as the correct color