# Efficiently converting an array of bitmaps to video

Tags: android, encoding, bitmap, android-canvas, android-bitmap

Using the Jcodec library, I had success producing and storing a video file on the Android file system from an array of Bitmap objects.

However, the **encoding** time takes way too long. I thought about scaling down each of the bitmaps to speed this up but this did not seem to work. Despite researching extensively, I struggled to find a helpful answer.

The below code is currently how I'm creating a bitmap, Where `canvasView.getWidth()` and `canvasView.getHeight()` correspond to **1920 x 1280** respectively.

```
public Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvasView.getWidth(), canvasView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Log.i("Downloading", "OWidth: " + b.getWidth() + " --- " + "OHeight: " +  b.getHeight());

    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);   // Essential

    v.draw(c);
    v.invalidate();
    v.requestLayout();

    return b;
}
```

I noticed when you change these two parameters to something smaller, IE:

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

The encoding speeds up dramatically.

The size of the entire view is **1920 x 1280**, so the `createBitmap` method shown above would only capture a small portion of the window (256 x 256), which is not what I require.

I need help finding a way to more efficiently encode an array of bitmaps to video or use the same method I am using but scaling down each bitmap while maintaining the entire image's visibility and speeding up the encoding process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FFmpeg to speed up your process of making video from images or bitmap

ffmpeg command:-

```
        File dir = your directory where image stores;
        String filePrefix = "picture"; //imagename prefix
        String fileExtn = ".jpg";//image extention
        filePath = dir.getAbsolutePath();
        File src = new File(dir, filePrefix + "%03d" + fileExtn);// image name should ne picture001, picture002,picture003 soon  ffmpeg takes as input valid



complexCommand = new String[]{"-i", src + "", "-c:v", "libx264", "-c:a", "aac", "-vf", "setpts=2*PTS", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-crf", "10", "-r", "15", "-shortest", "-y", "/storage/emulated/0/" + app_name + "/Video/" + app_name + "_Video" + number + ".mp4"};
```

here src = directory path which contains multiple images

you ca use writingminds library fro easily integrate ffmpeg in your project

https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

but ffmpeg increase apk size approx 18-20 mb

Comment: How can I use Ffmpeg exactly could.you explain? thank you!

Comment: That is awesome, but I do not have a directory of images, I have an array of bitmaps within the code. Can this also work with that?

Comment: you can but bitmap should be less size otherwise out of memory error occured so i suggest first store image in internal storage then access it

Answer (score 4):

I just put up this project that does this without external libs.

https://github.com/dburckh/bitmap2video

Answer (score 1):

for implementation use these

```
implementation 'org.jcodec:jcodec:0.2.5'
implementation 'org.jcodec:jcodec-android:0.2.5'
implementation 'org.jcodec:jcodec-javase:0.2.5'
implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'

fun creteRootPath(): File? {
    var file: File? = null
    try {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            file =  File(getApplicationContext()
     .getExternalFilesDir("")
      .toString() + File.separator + "UsamaSd.mp4")
        } else {
            file = File(Environment
      .getExternalStorageDirectory()
      .absolutePath.toString() 
       + File.separator + "UsamaSd.mp4")
        }
        if (file?.exists() == true) {
            file?.mkdirs()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        file // it will return null
    }
    return file
}
fun convertImagesToVideo() {
    try {//Rational(1, 1). SequenceEncoder
        val output = creteRootPath()
        val enc =
            
AWTSequenceEncoder.createWithFps(NIOUtils.writableChannel(output), 
Rational.R(2, 1))
        for (bitmap in arrayOfImagesFinalImages) {
            enc.encodeNativeFrame(fromBitmaps(bitmap))
        }
        enc.finish()
    } finally {
        NIOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
    }
}

fun fromBitmaps(src: Bitmap): Picture {
    val dst: Picture = Picture.create(src.width, src.height, RGB)
    AndroidUtil.fromBitmap(src, dst)
    return dst
}
```

for AndroidUtil class
https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/blob/master/android/src/main/org/jcodec/common/AndroidUtil.java

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple encoder:
Input: Drawable, Output: mp4 video

Invoke the function: startEncoding will generate 5 seconds mp4

```kotlin
private fun startEncoding() {
    val size = 720
    val bitrate = 3000000
    val mime = "video/avc"
    val format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(mime, size, size)
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitrate)
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 30)
    format.setInteger(
        MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
        MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface
    )
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1)
    val codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(mime)
    codec.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE)
    val surface: Surface = codec.createInputSurface()
    codec.start()

    // Create MediaMuxer and add track
    val VIDEO_PATH = createTempFile()

    val muxer = MediaMuxer(VIDEO_PATH.path, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)
    val bufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()

    encode(surface, bufferInfo, codec, muxer, size)
    // Release resources
    codec.stop()
    codec.release()
    muxer.stop()
    muxer.release()
}

private fun encode(
        surface: Surface,
        mBufferInfo: MediaCodec.BufferInfo,
        encoder: MediaCodec,
        muxer: MediaMuxer,
        size: Int
) {
  val DEQUEUE_TIMEOUT_USEC = 10000L
  val videoDuration = 5 * 1000000L
  var startTime: Long = -1
  var isEndOfStream = false
  val drawableList = listOf(R.drawable.birthday, R.drawable.birthday_cakes, R.drawable.happy_birthday)
  var index = 0
  while (true) {
      renderBitmap(drawableList[index], surface, size)
      val outputBufferIndex = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, DEQUEUE_TIMEOUT_USEC)
      val presentationTimeUs = mBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs
      if (startTime == -1L && presentationTimeUs > 0) {
          startTime = presentationTimeUs
      } else if (startTime != -1L) {
          if (presentationTimeUs - startTime > videoDuration && !isEndOfStream) {
              encoder.signalEndOfInputStream()
              isEndOfStream = true
          } else {
              index = (presentationTimeUs.toInt() / 1000000L).toInt() % drawableList.size
          }
      }
      if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
          Log.i("Tim", "no output available, spinning to await EOS")
          //break
      } else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
          Log.i("Tim", "start muxer")
          videoTrackIndex = muxer.addTrack(encoder.outputFormat)
          muxer.start()
      } else if (outputBufferIndex < 0) {
          Log.i("Tim", "unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer")
      } else {
          val encodedDataBuffer = encoder.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex)
              ?: throw RuntimeException("encoderOutputBuffer $outputBufferIndex was null")

          if (mBufferInfo.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG != 0) {
              Log.i("Tim", "ignoring BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG")
              mBufferInfo.size = 0
          }

          if (mBufferInfo.size != 0) {
              // adjust the ByteBuffer values to match BufferInfo
              encodedDataBuffer.position(mBufferInfo.offset)
              encodedDataBuffer.limit(mBufferInfo.offset + mBufferInfo.size)
              muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrackIndex, encodedDataBuffer, mBufferInfo)
          }

          encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false)

          if (mBufferInfo.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM != 0) {
              Log.i("Tim", "get EOS")
              break
          }
      }
  }
}

private fun renderBitmap(drawable: Int, surface: Surface, size: Int) {
  val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, drawable)
  val desiredHeight = (bitmap.height.toFloat() / bitmap.width.toFloat() * size).toInt()
  val scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, size, desiredHeight, true)
  val canvas: Canvas = surface.lockCanvas(null)
  canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null)
  surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
}
```